# Match only if no more of specific character

Tags: regex

I'm trying to match simple routes but can't seem to figure out how to not match if a slash is after a match.

```
// Example: localhost/person/1
/^person\/(.*)$/

// Example: localhost/person/1/details
/^person\/(.*)\/details$/
```

I can never get to the details route because the first one always matches.  So I need to figure out how to only match the first example if no slashes are after the parenthesis.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could replace `(.*)` with a [negated character set](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html), `([^\/]*)`, in order to match all characters except `/`.

```
/^person\/([^\/]*)$/
```

Comment: note `*` will match 0 characters - is that what is required, @Ralph?

Comment: Good point @Aprillion; I was using `*` because that's what was already used. `+` would likely be what the OP wants.

Comment: Thanks for that point.  You are correct, I should use a + instead of *

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the exact match you're after, you probably should be using

```
/^person\/\d+$/
```

for the first match, and

```
/^person\/\d+\/details$/
```

for the second.

These will match any numerical value after the "/person/" part and up to the following "/".

Comment: I believe I need a parenthesis pattern to catch matches because im using php preg_match.

Comment: @Ralph then by all means wrap the `\d` with parenthesis.

Comment: True, that would work just as well.  Thanks for your input.